# multiple if statements in c for beginners

Tags: c

code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
int a, b;
printf("enter a");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("enter b");
scanf("%d",&b);
if(a==1 && b<=8)
{
    printf("you");
}
else if(a==2 && b<=10)
{
    printf("you");
}
else
    printf("me");
}
getch();
}
```

i edit again my question i found solution check please if there any syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure the code you have posted compiles? there is a mess with the else.

Comment: Use `if else` instead of `if` for the second `if`.Also i am wondering how you are going to identify which `if` printed `you`?

Comment: Please read a good beginners book. C and C++ are two separate languages, `iostream.h` is not part of the C standard (and using `conio.h` is highly discouraged) and `void main(void)` isn't standard in either language

Comment: The C++ books are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Don't use Turbo C++ or another ancient compiler that still supports `#include <iostream.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not following general if-else block property

```
if(a==1 && b<=8)  // This is independent if 1
{
    printf("you");
}
```

Then this is another if-else either of if or else in this block will get executed independently of what has previously happened

```
if(a==2 && 5<b && b<=10)   //  This is independent if-else block 2
{
    printf("you");
}
else
    printf("me");
```

For achieving what you want it should be if, else if and else block

```
if(a==1 && b<=8)
{
    printf("you");
}
else if(a==2 && 5<b && b<=10)
{
    printf("you");
}
else
    printf("me");
```

Comment: Your parens are wrong.